# Attic door panel chain pulled off

Tags: attic, attic-door

If the attic door panel has a locking machanism and the pull chain has been pulled off, is there anyway to get the door open without damaging or replacing the door?

[image: attic door]

The 3 dots on the left side are the lock, and the hole to the right of those 3 dots is where the pull chain was.

Comment: Please add new information to your post, not comments.

Comment: Have you tried fashioning a wire hook to try and trigger the mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anyway to get the door open without damaging or replacing the door?

Yes, drill out the heads of the three carriage bolts and then replace them after you re-attach a new chain.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Ended up prying it really hard to open:

[image: latch]